# Zero-inflated Poisson models for matched data

Tags: r, poisson-regression, matching

I have a matched cohort of N=xx cases and the outcomes I'm interested in are counts (with many 0's). I know there exists conditional Poisson models for matched data where the outcomes are counts, but is it possible to run a zero-inflated conditional model in R? Thank you!

Comment: An FYI, you don't need a condition model; you can use a regular ZIP model and use cluster-robust standard errors with pair membership as the clustering variable. Conditional models that condition only on cluster membership (e.g., conditional logistic regression) tend not to perform well for estimating conditional effects after propensity score matching.

Comment: @Noah This was my first stab at it, but PROC GENMOD in SAS did not work - I used the repeated statement in my ZIP model and it would not let me do so. Any ideas how to run this in SAS or R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matched data, you can run a standard model as you would with non-matched data except that you must include the matching weights in the estimation and use cluster-robust standard errors with pair membership as the clustering variable. In R, this is straightforward after using `MatchIt` to perform the matching.

We'll need the following packages: `MatchIt` for the matching, `pscl` for the ZIP/ZINB model, and `lmtest` and `sandwich` for computing the cluster-robust standard errors and confidence intervals.

```
library(MatchIt); library(pscl); library(lmtest); library(sandwich)
```

In this example I'll let `A` be the binary treatment, `X1` and `X2` be covariates, and `Y` be the count outcome (which must be of integer class), and I'll let these exist within the dataset `dat`. First, we start with the matching, using whatever options you want (here I'll use full matching on the propensity score):

```
#Full matching on the PS for the ATT
m <- matchit(A ~ X1 + X2, data = dat, method = "full")
```

Next, we extract the matched dataset from the `matchit` output object using `match.data()`:

```
#Extract matched data
md <- match.data(m)
```

We can now use `zeroinfl()` from the `pscl` package to fit a ZIP or ZINB model (I'll use ZINB because that is almost always more appropriate):

```
#Fit the ZINB model
fit <- zeroinfl(Y ~ A, data = md, weights = weights, dist = "negbin")
```

Finally, we can use `coeftest()` and `vcovCL()` in the `lmtest` and `sandwich` packages, respectively, to compute the coefficients and standard errors:

```
#Coefficients and SEs
coeftest(fit, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster = ~subclass)
```

This will produce a coefficient table for the count model and the zero-inflation model, which can be interpreted as usual. The count model coefficient is the log of the count ratio and the zero-inflation coefficient is the log of the odds ratio. The standard errors will be correctly adjusted for the matching. To compute confidence intervals on the coefficients scale, you can replace `coeftest()` with `coefci()` in the code above. To compute the count ratio and the odds ratio, you would exponentiate the coefficients and confidence intervals, i.e., using

```
#Coefficients and CIs on the original scale
exp(coef(fit))
exp(coefci(fit, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster = ~subclass))
```

This procedure is the same as it is for matching with other outcome types. Instructions are detailed in the `MatchIt` [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) for estimating effects after matching.

---

Some pointers for those not familiar with R:

- If you don't have a package installed, install it using `install.packages("pkgname")`.
- To read in a CSV, use `read.csv()`; to read in a data object from another data format, e.g., a `sas7bdat` file from SAS, using functions from the `haven` package.
- To convert a variable to an integer, use `dat$Y <- as.integer(dat$Y)`. This is necessary for using `zeroinfl()`.
- To get help on any function, use `?fnname`, e.g., `?matchit`.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for this detailed answer. The problem I have is that I don't have the weights for the matched dataset. I was not responsible for the matching process, and I don't think the programmer can go back to obtain the weights either since the dataset is "finalized." I was hoping we could specify the different strata using `stratra(id)` or something like that in a model formula. Any experience with this? Thank you!

Comment: If you did 1:1 matching without replacement, you don't need matching weights. You would include pair membership using the `subclass` variable. It should go not into the model but rather into the estimation of the standard errors (i.e., in `coeftest()`).

Comment: If you did not perform 1:1 matching without replacement but have matched pair membership, you can compute matching weights from those. The formula for doing so is described in the `matchit()` documentation.

Comment: Hi Noah, we did do 1:1 matching without replacement. Based on this, if my strata variable is called `strata`, would I just do: `coeftest(fit, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster = ~strata)`?

Comment: I believe I got it to work! I used the `subclass` argument as you suggested and not the `cluster` argument (misread your post). Also, do you happen to have any article that may discuss this technique? I'd probably want to cite the article in the future. Thank you!

Comment: You can cite [Abadie and Spiess (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2020.1840383), who derive analytically that this is the preferred approach. You can check out the `MatchIt` documentation on estimating effects that I linked at the bottom of my post for more citations.

Comment: Hi @Noah, one last question: what is the difference between the `subclass` and `cluster` argument in `coeftest`?

Comment: `coeftest` doesn't have a `subclass` argument. The argument to `cluster` is passed to `vcovCL()`.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't follow correctly. This is the line of code I used: `coeftest(fit2, vcov. = vcovCL, subclass = ~strata)`. When I use `coeftest(fit2, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster= ~strata)`, I get the following error:  `number of observations in 'cluster' and 'estfun()' do not match`. Is it because of missing observations in my dataset?

Comment: The first line doesn't use the `strata` because `subclass` isn't an allowable argument. It's ignoring it. The second one is correct, but it is saying something is wrong. I'm not exactly sure what, though. Is `strata` the name of a variable in your dataset? Do you have any missing values in the variables included in the model (including `strata`)?

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks so much for all the help. Sorry for prolonging this discussion - we can move the discussion to chat if you prefer. None of the covariates in the model are missing, but there are missing data in the outcomes. Should I remove those observations prior to running the zero-inflated model? If I do remove those missing observations, let's say one person in the matched pair is missing data, should I remove the other individual as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117240/discussion-between-noah-and-user122514).